# How to use CocoaPods with LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, cocoapods, robovm

I have a LibGDX project which I can run on all platforms that are supported by LibGDX. Recently I started integrating the Google Nearby Messages API. I got it working on Android through platform-specific code, pretty much like the description on Google says it should be done. Now I want to integrate it in the iOS project, which uses RoboVM, but according to their documentation (https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started) I should use CocoaPods, which doesn't seem so straightforward for integration, especially in a LibGDX project. I hope someone with some experience in doing this can help me out, or point me to a project in which that's already done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, with RoboVM you use their available RoboPods supporting the most popular 3rd party intgrations, but not all.
Popular Google tools are listed there but I did not see Google Nearby Messages API, more info here: 
https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm-robopods